# Issue with Spring-Boot-Devtools compatibility with Intellij IDEA, compiltion error on Spring-Boot-Devtools live-reload

Tags: intellij-idea, spring-boot-devtools

I am facing hard time in the live reload using `Spring-Boot-Devtools`. Every time I update my controller class, the spring couldn't find the dependencies which are injected using constructor injection.

Suppose I am having this class

```
class MyController{

  private MyService myService;

  public MyController(MyService myService){    
    this.myService= myService;
  }   

  //controller methods

}
```

Changes to any of the controller methods or the `MyService`'s methods would result in some error like: `constructor in com.example.MyController required a bean of type 'com.example.MyService' that could not be found`

Whereas if I run the same code on the Eclipse, the live reload works fine.

**IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1.2 (Ultimate Edition)

JRE: 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49 x86_64

JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o

macOS 10.13.6**

[image: gradle]
[image]

Comment: Do you have [build/run delegated to Gradle](https://i.imgur.com/AmWjMZR.png)? Does it help if you switch this option to IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: @CrazyCoder I don't have such options into my Gradle settings. Please see the updated question for screenshots.

Comment: Is your project Maven based? Can you share [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can reproduce the issue?

Comment: Yes, it's a maven project. I think I can't provide you a sample project. I tried creating a sample project, but live-reload is working fine there. May be my original project is quite heavy. I can't recreate that whole project for the issue to be reproduced, sorry.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Can you please suggest some other configs I can check in my project?

Comment: Sorry, can't help without MCVE.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I somehow manage to create a sample project and pushed it to GitHub. Please clone it from here https://github.com/Puspendert/intellij-liveReload.git. Also created a screen recording which will help you understand the issue better. here is the link https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Au7pIPTHozyc8XUznb3cpF1QH8Vavc-A

Comment: Can't reproduce in 2019.2.2 release. How do you update the classes? Do you run Build | Build?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199390/discussion-between-thecoder-and-crazycoder).